# Keeping ref to children created by function as child prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, map-function, react-proptypes

I currently have a `Feed` component. It accepts a `data` prop, which is an array of items, and a `children` prop, which is intended to be a function to map the data to a DOM element.

Right now, I am trying to create the functionality to scroll to any element in this `data` property that was mapped by the `children` function. However, that means that I will need to store a reference to it. I'm not sure of the appropriate syntax/api for that. Here's my basic code:

```
class ScrollableFeed extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array,
    children: PropTypes.func,
  };

  container = null;

  render() {
    const { data, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={styles.feed}
        onScroll={this.onScroll}
        ref={e => { this.container = e; }}
      >
        {data.map(children)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In order to scroll to a component, I will need a reference to the dom elements that have been mapped out by the `children` function.

How can this be done in react?

Comment: Could you share the code of the `Feed` component?

Comment: oops sorry, it's the code right there for `ScrollableFeed`, just a mismatch of types

Comment: Okay, I meant for the parent code of `ScrollableFeed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found a solution. DOM elements have a property called [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes). Therefore, I can just reference my container and grab the child nodes, which would have been mapped out by `children`. I can then grab nodes by index.

```
getNodeAtIndex(index) {
  const { childNodes = [] } = this.container;
  const nodeIndex = Math.min(Math.max(index, 0), childNodes.length - 1);
  return childNodes[nodeIndex];
}
```